# Anyone have experience in building an Eclipse RCP application with Gradle?

Tags: build, eclipse-rcp, gradle

Does anyone have experience in building an application based on Eclipse RCP with [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org)? I'd like especially to know:

- How reasonable is it to build Eclipse RCP plugins and products with Gradle?
- Are there any Gradle plugins to achieve this task (like the Tycho plugin for Maven)?
- Do you know any tutorials or articles describing such an approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions is three years old, nevertheless... Here is the solution: https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff

Comment: The scaffold task downloads eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64, then downloads http://mirror.netcologne.de/eclipse//eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4.2-201502041700/eclipse-SDK-4.4.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz and then fails.

Answer (score 4):

there is a pdePlugin available for Gradle written by Gregory Boissinot. The plugin is available at https://github.com/gboissinot/gradleplugins. It contains two examples about 
a) building product based app
b) building feature based app

As a matter of fact, the plugin is a wrapper of the pde build. internally it starts the eclipse pde build.

regards,
René