# How To Build RCP Plug-ins with Gradle

Tags: gradle, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a couple projects that make up a module, and I want to build them automatically. The module consists of a plain JAR API, an EJB, an EAR, a plug-in and a RCP product, so building it with either Maven or Tycho is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757888/plain-jars-and-bundles-in-the-same-reactor). I want to evaluate if it is possible using Gradle.

The last couple days I tried to figure out how that is done, and I'm not sure why there is so little support to build RCP applications using Gradle, especially since Gradle has overtaken Maven on the build automation front.

What I tried:

- [BuildMonkey](https://github.com/MONKEY-WORKS/BuildMonkey) - gets it's repositories directly (and unmodifiable) from https://ftp.heanet.ie, which is down
- [Wuff!](https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff) - doesn't work with the latest Gradle version
- [GradlePlugins](https://github.com/gboissinot/gradleplugins) - for Gradle 0.9, last commit was 8 years ago
- [DiffPlug](https://github.com/diffplug/gradle-and-eclipse-rcp) - example project leads to `NoClassDefFoundError`

Is there some great tool I'm missing? Something has to work? Especially considering Tycho isn't in use either. Maybe it's really Eclipse RCP that nobody uses anymore?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879646/anyone-have-experience-in-building-an-eclipse-rcp-application-with-gradle) is similar, but old - and I tried the tools in the answers.

Comment: Eclipse RCP applications are widely used (especially as in-house applications) and Tycho is mostly used for building them. Why do you say the opposite?

Comment: @howlger This has nothing to do with the question, has it? Problems like [the Tycho target platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143472/set-a-target-platform-for-pom-xml-based-repositories), which doesn't allow to start a product or test **from the IDE** come to mind. Maybe I should have specified "professional environment", but Eclipse keeps repeating "in-house application" and I keep hearing "they don't know either if anybody uses it".

Comment: You ask how to drive a nail with a screwdriver because screwdrivers have overtaken hammers on the build tool front (keep hearing people saying "they don't know either if anybody uses nails")? Eclipse is based on OSGi with bundles that can be started and stopped at runtime. To resolve dependencies, more metadata is required than a Maven or Gradle repository provides (e. g. to resolve `Import-Package` statements). Maven without Tycho and Gradle are designed to resolve dependencies for a flat classpath and cannot be used to find the JAR that is required to resolve an `Import-Package` statement.

Comment: @howlger I applaud the bravery to delete the comment stating the fact that _some companies_ silent anybody who questions their methods. :D

Comment: did you find a way to do it? like a grade plugin? thx

Comment: @titou10 Nope. I guess the only way is to use Tycho for the RCP build.